# JSON Exception no result returned

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, encode

Android application that receives ID ,Name and Email from PHP file ID , Name , Email sent as JSON response to Android Application , the problem is when i click get data no data is received and i get an exception in the LogCat
here is my code,PHP file and stack trace
MainActivity

```
   package com.example.colcheck;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.colcheck.Library.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView uid;
    TextView name1;
    TextView email1;
    Button Btngetdata;

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://localhost/new/check2.php";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

    JSONArray user = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
             name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
             email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {

                 System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

                 String id="";
                 String name="";
                 String email="";
                if(json.has("id"))
                     id = json.getString("id");

                 if(json.has("name"))
                      name = json.getString("name");

                 if(json.has("TAG_EMAIL"))
                      email = json.getString("TAG_EMAIL");

                                 //Set JSON Data in TextView
                                 uid.setText(id);
                                 name1.setText(name);
                                 email1.setText(email);

                         } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }

         }
    }

}
```

PHP file with json response

```
 <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","pet_home");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='test' AND password='123'");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if($row_cnt>0){     
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
         $data = array('success'=>true, 'user'=>array("TAG_ID" => $row['id'], "TAG_NAME"=> $row['name'], "TAG_EMAIL" =>$row['email'])); 
     }else{
         $data = array('success'=>false);
     }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data);



    mysqli_close($con);


    ?>
```

After doing this no response comes back to android app Here is stacktrace seems like there is an exception

```
11-30 17:06:13.679: I/System.out(3474): JSON Response : {"TAG_USER":{"id":"OFF","TAG_EMAIL":"OFF","name":"OFF"},"success":true}
```

Comment: there is no tag name `user` so only that error.

Comment: didn't get what you mean please explain more thanks

Comment: can you print `json` in log cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

if your `json` is like this

```
{"id":"OFF","TAG_EMAIL":"OFF","name":"OFF"}
```

then

you can check whether that tag name present or not

```
System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

if(json.has("id"))
    String id = json.getString("id");

if(json.has("name"))
    String name = json.getString("name");

if(json.has("TAG_EMAIL"))
    String email = json.getString("TAG_EMAIL");
```

**EDIT:**

your parsing like below

```
user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
```

there is no `JSONArray` only `JSONObject` so you cannot parse `JSONObject` as `JSONArray` then there is no `user` as `JSONArray`

**EDIT 1 :**

```
try {

System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

if(json.has("id"))
    String id = json.getString("id");

if(json.has("name"))
    String name = json.getString("name");

if(json.has("TAG_EMAIL"))
    String email = json.getString("TAG_EMAIL");

                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                uid.setText(id);
                name1.setText(name);
                email1.setText(email);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
try {

System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

 JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("TAG_USER");

if(c.has("id"))
    String id = c.getString("id");

if(c.has("name"))
    String name = c.getString("name");

if(c.has("TAG_EMAIL"))
    String email = c.getString("TAG_EMAIL");

                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                uid.setText(id);
                name1.setText(name);
                email1.setText(email);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i updated my post with exception no value for user 
i edited the id ,name and email but i didn't get what to edit in user so that it fixes the problem

Comment: @user1928775 can you print `json` response in log cat

Comment: @user1928775 try my codes.  remove `user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER); and JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0); `

Comment: after editing the code using your second edit i got in the logcat the response posted 
11-30 17:06:13.679: I/System.out(3474): JSON Response : {"TAG_USER":{"id":"OFF","TAG_EMAIL":"OFF","name":"OFF"},"success":true}